# Information about Ghostscript

Tags: c++, image-processing, ghostscript, raster

I'm a neo devoloper. I want to develop a Raster Image Processor using Ghostscript. I'm searching for a manual and guide of Ghostscript. I search on internet but there aren't many information about it. I'm searching for any developer who can give me some information about Ghostscript.

Comment: Visit the Ghostscript tag information; there is some information there.  For the rest, this question is off-topic according to the rules of SO, though you've got some useful information in the answer (which you should accept unless there's a good reason not to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also covered in the #ghostscript IRC channel on Freenode; The Ghostscript documentation is supplied as HTML files, you can find a copy [here](https://ghostscript.com/Documentation.html) and if you clone the source from our Git repository you will find the files in /ghostpdl/doc.

The Ghostscript executable, supplied on the platforms we support, demonstrates how to use the front-end API, which is sufficient to build an application.

Developing a Ghostscript device to drive a specific printer (or other output engine) is more complex, the documentation does describe the process and there are **numerous** devices supplied as source to look at. Nevertheless its still a somewhat involved process and anyone attempting this would probably benefit from talking to the developers. Best place for that is the #ghostscript IRC channel.

Compiling for other operating systems can be tricky, Ghostscript is a 'mature' piece of software and already supports building for a variety of operating systems, old and new, as well as cross-compiling for embedded targets. Again, if you want to do this, and are having trouble, best thing to do is come and ask.